# Is there a new Imperial Stockmarket splash screen?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

So I opened up the game and it showed a screen splash screen for something, I think it said "imperial stockmarket" is this a new update, or am I just seeing things?

Answer (score 3):

You are not seeing things. There have suddenly been in-game ads appearing when you open the game.  I had one for Holonet, and the Infini-Lift elevator upgrade.  The game version appears the same, so this must have been an update pushed out silently via the game server and not a full update.

I haven't seen anything in the game referring to an Imperial Stock Market yet, though.   There is not an updated level for it yet.

Answer (score -2):

The "Imperial Stockmarket" is referring to Imperial Bux, that's all.  Nothing to see here folks, move along.

Comment: What is this based upon?  Is it showing a picture of Imperial Bux?